# Capture all redirected urls in a WebView

Tags: android, url, webview

Iam loading a url into a `WebView`. It loads a login page. After login the user gets redirected to different urls. When he reaches the last url he gets authenticated. I want to load another activity when the last url matches a String that I am forming.

Any help on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have asked this question 2-3 times now my friend.

I am not sure if i have a proper answer to your issue.

If i was in your place i would try to use some tools to fetch all the url's occurring due to the redirection.
Try using tools like

> http://redirectdetective.com/
>
> http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/

and in your onPageFinished
get the current url of the webview using

```
String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
```

and compare it with the final url after redirection
and then launch your intent

Comment: @user3518278 thanx for the help. When I load my url it opens up a login page.That is the last detination(Checked with first link you provided) But after login the user gets authenticated. I want the url after he is authenticated

Comment: so why dont open the login page, enter the credentials and then check what url comes just right after that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the urls try below code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains("yourURL.com")){
            //Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test.class);
           //startActivity(intent);
                  webView.stopLoading(); //this line is to stop loading the webview
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to stop loading the webview when the url matches. how do I do it?

Comment: see my edit...webView.stopLoading(); line added this line will stop your webview to load...